# Архитектура приложения vlc видеоплеер - распознование

Tags: qt, opencv, vlc

Всем привет, есть VLC плеер, есть библиотека по распознованию текста.
VLC плеер принимает видеопоток и отдает каждое изображение в функцию распознования.
Приложение пишу на qt. Теперь вопрос, как эти вещи объединить, распознование не будет успевать
за плеером, поэтому придется каждый кадр отдавать в отдельный поток.Во избежании тормозов 
в самом плеере. Пока не представляю как. Если у кого опыт, поделитесь пожалуйста архитектурой такого решения.

Comment: Можно поподробнее, откуда vlc плеер принимает видеопоток, где находится функция распознавания и как он передает в неё изображение?

Comment: VLC принимает поток с камеры. Функция распознования находится в отдельном классе, как раз в параметры функции кладется изображение